# Representatons of dimension $1$ on $D_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> Prove that there are $4$ distinct representations on $D_4$ with dimension $1$ (where the field is $\mathbb{C}$).

We have just started learning representations. Getting this question, what straight confused me is why there has to be a representation of $D_4$ with dimension $1$? $D_4$ can be thought of as the co-ordinates of a square, but they are $2$ dimensional (each element has $2$ co-ordinates).

Comment: Remember that representations need not be faithful (i.e. there can be plenty of elements from the group that act trivially on the given representation). In this case, are you familiar with representations of abelian groups?

Comment: Every group has a representation of dimension $1$ (over any field) known as the trivial representation. You just map every group element to the $1 \times 1$ identity matrix. Another representation of dimension $1$ for any dihedral group is to map all of the rotations to the identity and all of the reflections to minus the identity. But you still have to find two more!

Comment: To amplify what Derek suggests-try thinking of what the kernel of the representations might be (I suggest you think about subgroups of $D_4$ of order $4$-these are automatically normal); that is which elements of $D_4$ map to $1 \in \Bbb C^{\times}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are able to use here. The easiest way to resolve this question is to use the Wedderburn-Artin theorem (plus Maschke's Theorem). This states that
$$\mathbb{C} D_4\cong M_{n_1}(\mathbb{C})\oplus\cdots\oplus M_{n_k}(\mathbb{C})$$
where $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ are the dimensions of the (pairwise non-isomorphic) simple modules and satisfy
$$n_1^2+\cdots+n_k^2=8.$$
This last equation simply says that the dimensions on both side of the isomorphism must agree and has unique solution $1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+2^2=8$. It follows that there are $4$ non-isomorphic $1$-dimensional modules and a unique irreducible $2$-dimensional module.

On the other hand, this is a small example and you can probably produce these representations by hand. Though that would take more effort.